# Wrong products show up on substore main page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, mysql-indexes

**We use Magento ver. 1.9.3.6**

We have multiple substores in our shop
In substore with **store_id=3** products must be shown from **cat_id=233**
In CMS page I added:

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="233" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But the substore home page is also showing products from other categories??
I disabled all cache and enabled SQL logging.

This is the SQL Magento produces:

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`description`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`manufacturer`, `e`.`manufacturer_value`, `e`.`image`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`color`, `e`.`color_value`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`status`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`ean`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `salable`, `at_bestsellers`.`bestsellers` 
                           FROM `catalog_product_flat_3` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON 
                          cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND 
                                      cat_index.store_id=3 AND 
                             cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND 
                             cat_index.category_id = '233' AND 
                                     cat_index.is_parent=1

 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON 
                       price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND 
                              price_index.website_id = '1' AND 
                        price_index.customer_group_id = 0

 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status` ON 
                      e.entity_id = stock_status.product_id AND 
                      stock_status.website_id=1

 LEFT JOIN `am_sorting_bestsellers` AS `at_bestsellers` ON 
                     (at_bestsellers.`id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_bestsellers.store_id = '3') WHERE 
        (e.status = 1) ORDER BY `salable` desc, `bestsellers` desc, `at_bestsellers`.`bestsellers` DESC LIMIT 12
```

Now I took a faulty product that was showing on the page:
it has entity_id 3601

Now when I do

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product_index` WHERE `product_id` = 3601 AND `store_id` = 3
```

Then I get 3 results with one result in category 233 ?? (other 2 correct for this product)
In the backoffice I checked this product, and only 2 categories are checked.

How is this possible??

When I look in `catalog_category_product` there the correct results (for that product) are given.

It seems `catalog_category_product_index` has faulty entries...
I re-indexed all products, without any success

Can anyone give me some guidance how to solve this problem?

Kind regards
John